# Display previous tab on remove a tab jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a widget for the tabs in my web page where I add tabs dynamically, I am trying to remove a tab works fine, but not able to display the previous tab, even though it is in active the respective div is not visible.

The code I am using is:

```
tabs.delegate("span.ui-icon-close", "click", function () {              
            var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
            $("#" + panelId).remove();
            tabs.tabs("refresh");            
        });
```

this has to work normally, but didn't

so I tried showing the div my self by adding below line of code in the above function.

```
 $(
    $(this).closest("li").prev("li").children("a").attr("href")
  )
  .attr("aria-expanded", true)
  .attr("aria-hidden", false)
  .css("display", "block");
```

when i debug my line of code it is forcing the div to display, after going out of the function some where in to plug-in files it is changing the div settings and making it not visible.

HTML:

```
   <div id="dynamicTabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width:960px;">
       <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-13" aria-selected="false">
                <a id="ui-id-13" class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="#tabs-1" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">Add</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-18" aria-selected="true">
                 <a id="ui-id-18" class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="#tabs-2" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">dfbgbb</a>
                 <span class="ui-icon-close">X</span>
           </li>
    </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-labelledby="ui-id-13" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">Tab 1 content.</div>
   <div id="tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom selected" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;" aria-labelledby="ui-id-18" role="tabpanel">cvxbxcvxcvxcv</div>
</div>
```

I guess there might be some problem in the script, but I am not able figure out what. 
Does any one had same issue or know any work around plz let me know thanks................

Comment: can you post HTML as well ?

Comment: before removing : http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

Comment: We can solve it, if there is a jsfiddle to work with, now i'm not sure how to recreate your problem.